How can I extract data from a multipage PDF into a single CSV file using camelot python library?
I've got a PDF file consisting of 4 pages of data. The first 3 pages contain 3 tables with the same columns. After some research I've found a pretty good python lib called camelot-py. Would it be possible to generate a single CSV file containing all data from the PDF file (with the condition all tables have the same columns a data types), using camelot-py?
I implemented this first version below, inspired on this post. The problem is that it generates multiple CSV files one per table found inside de PDF file, and I need a single CSV file containing all the data from the PDF pages. I would like to have just one file in the end of the process. Would it be possible using this camelot-py python lib, maybe in conjunction with another one (like pandas)?
# First version
import camelot 

def pdf2csv_single(pdf_filename, csv_filename):

    tables = camelot.read_pdf(pdf_filename)

    if tables:
        # Se sim, salvar a primeira tabela em um arquivo CSV
        tables.export(f'{csv_filename}', f='csv')
        print("Data successfully extracted to CSV")
    else:
        print("No table found")


One of the simpler ways to extract GUI text as tabular is via Java Tabula.
Since we are working with a "graphics" format (PDF) it is most sensible to use heads up graphical editors, same as you would use an image app for pixel manipulation or Graphical WP for text style processing.
PDF charted characters on left Visualisation of extraction upper right. Character separated values result lower right.

If you want to run headless then use PDFtoText and inject say commas to replace the voids.
                                                            TABLE 1 - RANDOM DIGITS

                                 11164    36318    75061    37674    26320    75100    10431    20418    19228    91792
                                 21215    91791    76831    58678    87054    31687    93205    43685    19732    08468
                                 10438    44482    66558    37649    08882    90870    12462    41810    01806    02977
                                 36792    26236    33266    66583    60881    97395    20461    36742    02852    50564
                                 73944    04773    12032    51414    82384    38370    00249    80709    72605    67497

                                 49563    12872    14063    93104    78483    72717    68714    18048    25005    04151
                                 64208    48237    41701    73117    33242    42314    83049    21933    92813    04763
                                 51486    72875    38605    29341    80749    80151    33835    52602    79147    08868
                                 99756    26360    64516    17971    48478    09610    04638    17141    09227    10606
                                 71325    55217    13015    72907    00431    45117    33827    92873    02953    85474

                                 65285    97198    12138    53010    94601    15838    16805    61004    43516    17020
                                 17264    57327    38224    29301    31381    38109    34976    65692    98566    29550
                                 95639    99754    31199    92558    68368    04985    51092    37780    40261    14479
                                 61555    76404    86210    11808    12841    45147    97438    60022    12645    62000
                                 78137    98768    04689    87130    79225    08153    84967    64539    79493    74917

TABLE 1 - RANDOM DIGITS

11164,36318,75061,37674,26320,75100,10431,20418,19228,91792
21215,91791,76831,58678,87054,31687,93205,43685,19732,08468
10438,44482,66558,37649,08882,90870,12462,41810,01806,02977
36792,26236,33266,66583,60881,97395,20461,36742,02852,50564
73944,04773,12032,51414,82384,38370,00249,80709,72605,67497

49563,12872,14063,93104,78483,72717,68714,18048,25005,04151
64208,48237,41701,73117,33242,42314,83049,21933,92813,04763
51486,72875,38605,29341,80749,80151,33835,52602,79147,08868
99756,26360,64516,17971,48478,09610,04638,17141,09227,10606
71325,55217,13015,72907,00431,45117,33827,92873,02953,85474

65285,97198,12138,53010,94601,15838,16805,61004,43516,17020
17264,57327,38224,29301,31381,38109,34976,65692,98566,29550
95639,99754,31199,92558,68368,04985,51092,37780,40261,14479
61555,76404,86210,11808,12841,45147,97438,60022,12645,62000
78137,98768,04689,87130,79225,08153,84967,64539,79493,74917



In fact tabula is a very good library, it was the first one I've found and tried to use. But it requires you to install Java and I needed a fast solution to an emergency. Additionally, I'm not so fluent in java as I'm in python, so I tried to find some lib in python. I was searching some tool to use in conjunction to jupyter notebooks, because this just a part of a greater process of data cleaning and standardization. But your suggestions was very useful and informational. Does it have a Docker image.

I've found this Docker specification for Tabula https://github.com/asnelling/tabula-docker.
